# WP API ignores filter parameter

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to return a list of posts or media via the Rest API

But it seems that when a filter incorrectly specified then a whole page of results is passed back.

So a curl command like

```
curl -gv  "myamazingsite.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?filter[id]=123"
```

returns all media items, instead of a empty list.

now

```
curl -gv  "myamazingsite.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?filter[year]=2016"
```

I get all media for that year.

and

```
curl -gv  "myamazingsite.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?filter[year]=2015"
```

returns an empty list [] , because there isn't any..fine.

So, I assume that id is not a valid filter argument, but why do I not get an error message?

The documentation for filter arg just links to wp_query method, which seems to be all about the PHP function, I admit I know very little about PHP, so I find this very confusing as to what it is saying...

Answer (score 0):

WP API will ignore filter values it doesn't understand, so the following are essentially identical:

```
curl -gv  "myamazingsite.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?filter[id]=123"
curl -gv  "myamazingsite.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"
```

Any filter keys that are valid, however, will be used to filter the results, so if there are no images for the year 2015, the following will return nothing (`[]`).

```
curl -gv  "myamazingsite.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?filter[year]=2015"
```

I'm not quite sure what you want your first curl command to return, if you could clarify, I'd be happy to expand this answer.

Comment: If I run a query and the query is wrong/incorrect, I would expect and error message. Not a pile of results. How do I know the query is wrong?

Comment: I realise now that that filter[id] should be filter[p], p must be a WordPress thing. ( Again as an API user how I'm I expected to know that?)

Comment: Well, I'm not going to argue with you on that :)
The filter-functionality for WP API is mostly for advanced users familiar with `WP_Query` in WordPress development, so I guess the creators of WP API didn't deem in necessary to include the documentation for `WP_Query` in their documentation – then again, that's what this StackExchange site is for - Q&A about WordPress! Hope you got it to work :)